# What's the most easy way to add a new row to an ng-grid table with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-grid table that's populated with data. I looked through the documentation and searched on Google but I can find no examples of how to add a new row to the grid.

Is there any special way that people use to add new data. I am just hoping to find some examples that I can work from. So far I found nothing. I wish that the ng-grid site could have just one example. I'm sure I am not the only person who has needed to add a row to an ng-grid.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to just add a new record to the array that the grid is bound to in your controller? Being that it is bound to that data the new row should appear automatically.

Comment: But for the new row to appear then is there a way I need to tell Angular that that the row has been added? I did see some reference to doing it with a template but there's no good example. ng-grid seems really good but it's a shame the examples do not include adding and delete of a row. I would have thought that's something almost everyone would want to know about.

Comment: If the binding is not taking automatically you may need to call apply on the $scope to force it to rebind. Search for apply here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the example: <strike>http://plnkr.co/edit/1uLcok?p=preview</strike>

(fixed a broken link to the library):   http://plnkr.co/edit/GdstXN?p=preview

You can simply modify the array.  It is angularJs' responsible for updating the view.
(If the data modification happens outside of angularjs, then you need to call `$apply`
against the `scope`.)

Comment: Isn't Working your Example